# {textarea} smarty php

Tags: php, html, textarea, smarty

further to a previous question, I have this code:

```
   <p class="required">
  {err for="msg"}
   <!--{{label {t _inquiry_msg}:}}-->
   {textarea onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Skriv her';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Skriv her') this.value='';"}

  {/err}
 </p>
```

And I want the output to be

```
<textarea onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Skriv her';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Skriv her') this.value='';">Write here!</textarea>
```

I tried `{/textarea}` but it didn't work in my template file.

Also, using html `<>` tags doesn't work, it breaks the page.

http://euroworker.no/Konftel-300-IP.268

Is it possible to make this in smarty/php?

Thanks :)

Comment: Huh? What's wrong with `<textarea>`?

Comment: That won't work for some reason.

Comment: if the plain HTML won't work my guess is that it's preceded by either invalid HTML or some output in your template that is breaking the HTML. There's no reason the plain HTML shouldn't work.

Comment: I have validated the page and there are a few errors, one includes an additional `value` tag that is inserted from somewhere.. I can't figure that one out either. The company states that this system should validate, but it never does. 

But other than that, it's alt atttributes in images that shouldn't affect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write directly:

```
<textarea onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Skriv her';" 
          onfocus="if(this.value=='Skriv her') this.value='';">Write here!</textarea>
```

If it does not work, it has nothing to do with smarty.

Answer (score 1):

Just put:

```
<textarea onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Skriv her';" 
          onfocus="if(this.value=='Skriv her') this.value='';">Write here!</textarea>
```

Smarty will not replace anything.

Comment: This does not work, I already tried to use HTML tags, but it breaks the page.

Comment: if that breaks the page your problem has NOTHING to do with smarty.

Answer (score 1):

You really ought to start with [the W3C markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feuroworker.no%2FKonftel-300-IP.268&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.767) and than try to find your bug.

Answer (score 0):

You missed something here:

```
<!--{{label {t _inquiry_msg}:}}-->
```

I don't know what this code should do but the error is definitely here

```
<!--{{label} {t _inquiry_msg}:}}-->
```

then the HTML should work fine

```
<textarea onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Skriv her';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Skriv her') this.value='';">Write here!</textarea>
```

Comment: Try remove the comment ( <!-- ) and leave only the <textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps, and keep commenting:-

1. Please try to remove the whole
   commented line, between the "{err
   for="msg"}" line & the "{textarea}"
   line.
2. Now remove the curly braces from the
   "textarea" line of code, and write
   plain HTML, just like "Luis
   Melgratti" posted in his answer.
3. If possible, try to upload some
   screenshot images of the error,
   which the page is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty 3 or Smarty 2? Because in version 3 the tag filtering `{...}` has been way improved.

Comment: I am not sure, how can I find out?

Comment: If you don't know which you've downloaded, check either Smarty.php or README.txt provided with your Smarty. You should find the version number somewhere inside.
The folder structure changed a lot. You could simply compare the main folders inside the "lib" directory and compare with verison 2 and version 3.

Comment: It's version 2.6.13. but you see I was bought in to edit some layout features of a Smarty website, so I have NO idea what or who has done what or where things are.. I'm VERY new to Smarty.

Comment: Try upgrading to Smarty3. As I said, its grammar analyser (the way it detects Smarty tags) has been improved a lot, plus other things.